# Can Duet 3 Roto Toolboard work with BigTreeTech mainboard?

Tags: diy-3d-printer, electronics

I am considering a CAN Bus setup with [BIGTREETECH Manta M8P, V1.1 or V2.0](https://biqu.equipment/collections/control-board/products/manta-m4p-m8p?variant=39859521716322) with a [Raspberry Pi CM4 2GB WiFi](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/compute-module-4/?variant=raspberry-pi-cm4102008) as a mainboard because it is overkill and it shouldn't limit me in any way in a foreseeable future. I am also interested in [Revo Roto](https://e3d-online.com/pages/revo-roto-landing-page) as a tool head because it's light and all-in-one solution for a well-established easy-to-use ecosystem. It's advertised as compatible with high-flow nozzles and 60 W / 300 °C heaters, and I am not going to print very high temp materials. To avoid drag chains, I would want a CAN Bus setup, but the only solution for Roto I can find is [Duet 3 Roto Toolboard](https://www.duet3d.com/Duet3RotoToolboard).

I don't know the first thing about CAN Bus. Would these two boards work with each other? And what would I need to add, to make it work?

All these boards together add up to a pretty penny, so I don't want to spend that much only to waste some of it and never be able to get it to work. I am not associated with any of these manufacturers, if I were I would make them find answers for me. Links are only for reference.